# Ubuntu 14.04 Splash

Tags: plymouth

I want to change my Ubuntu Splash screen image or theme, when searching in Google, I find some tutorial to change splash.

First one is splash screen inside this folder (/lib/plymouth/), I can find it :)
The second one is images inside this folder (/usr/share/images/usplash or /usr/share/images/xsplash), I can't find this folder, but I found this folder /usr/share/images/desktop-base. Inside this folder there are some images file that contain 'splash' in the name of the images.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching and exploring my root folder, it seems plymouth folder is the right splash screen folder.
We need to change the images in themes folder and edit the script.